# Como editar una clase HTML , desde Javascript

Tags: javascript

Buenas quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy realizando en javascript 
para que una clase se pueda cambiar de color , pero no se que estoy haciendo mal 
quisiera que me pueda ayudar este es mi codigo :

**Javascript:**

```
 <script>
          $(document).ready(function () {

              document.getElementsByClassName("colourButton").style.color = "#FF0000";

          });
    </script>
```

**HTML :**

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                <tr >
                    <th>nombre</th>
                    <th>apellidos</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="colourButton">
                    <td >piero</td>
                    <td>Flores</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
    </form>
```

me sale esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Solo por curiosidad, en que input tienes agregada esa clase ?

Comment: @gama984 estoy agregando a un   <tr class="colourButton">

Comment: jajajaja, si estaba revisando con mas detalle y lo vi, ahora te hago un ejemplo de como podrías hacer el cambio

Comment: @gama984 muchas Gracias.

Comment: Cuando es por clase el método te regresa una lista de nodos que contiene todos los elementos que tengan esa clase, por lo que acceder a ellos tiene que ser `document.getElementsByClassName("colourButton")[0].style.color = "#FF0000";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema, es que el método para obtener clases, obtiene una colección de elementos HTML, con la misma clase. Entonces es como un array, pero no puedes usar sus métodos, por eso uso Array.from() , que es como que lo transformara para trabajar con el array

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
  var c = document.getElementsByClassName("misma");
  Array.from(c).forEach(e => {
    e.style.color = "red";
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Ejemplo clases</title>
</head>
<body>
  <i class="misma">Soy de la misma clase</i>
  <br><br>
  <b class="misma">Yo tambieen!!</b>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mi estimado @eduardo me sale un error aqui ::    <script>
              window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
                  var c = document.getElementsByClassName("misma");
                  Array.from(c).forEach(e => {
                      e.style.color = "red";
              });
          });

    </script>

Comment: No veo el error, ese es el código encerrado en etiqueta script, además ejecutalo.. Funciona perfectamente

Comment: adjunte la imagen del error en mi pregunta esta es la ultima imagen

Comment: Mmm, solo adjuntaste una imágen del código, cuál es el error? Este método es el mejor para iterar con clases

Comment: Date cuenta, que la clase que yo puse, no se llama igual que la tuya, la mía era solo un ejemplo. Cambia el nombre de la clase por la tuya, quizás eso te falla.

Comment: Si tienes razon ,lo puse ahora el mismo nombre de mi clase pero ahora en la console ya no me sale error pero no se pinta adjuntare la imagen

Comment: Pero, ahí tienes otra clase. Realmente a qué le quieres aplicar el estilo?, como se llama tu clase? , porque con el ejemplo que pusiste, sí funciona.

Comment: te explico mi hermano yo estoy realizando que la tabla se cree de forma dinamica gracias a url lo realize y me salio de maravilla :

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/display-data-in-Asp-Net-using-jquery-datatables-plugin/

cuando le di en inspector de seguimiento vi que dentro tenia una clase llamada sorting_1 lo que queria de forma dinamica en javascript se ponga de otro color . no se si me entiendo mi hermano

Comment: Pues si te fijas, tu clase que contiene a esos elementos se llama "odd" , reemplaza la clase por odd, y dime que tal

Comment: si coloque el odd pero no salio no mostro ningun cambio

Comment: Bueno Pierro, tu código es ya cosa tuya, yo ya te dí la solución. Ahora queda que tú lo implementes en donde lo necesites

Comment: Puede que no te salga porque quizas estas usando una version del navegador que no soporta las funciones flecha. Sustituye e => { ... } por function(e) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

Trata esto, le inserte la librería de jquery, espero que te funcione.

```js
          $(document).ready(function () {

     document.getElementsByClassName("colourButton")[0].style.color = "#FF0000";

          });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                <tr >
                    <th>nombre</th>
                    <th>apellidos</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="colourButton">
                    <td >piero</td>
                    <td>Flores</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
    </form>
```

Espero que te funcione.

Comment: Mi estimado esta bien pero el mio seria como una clase no un id

Comment: listo, jajajaja espero que te funcione jajaja